# Why doesn't search engines like Google, Bing, Yahoo try to use the space available on left side(under the logo)?

Tags: user-interface, web

I am onto learning CSS and tried replicating search engine web pages. Unlike websites, search engine pages have a white space on the left-hand side(under the logo). Is there some importance to it with regards to web design?

[Google Search Results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ngU.png)

[Yahoo Search Results Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ba6K.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

White space is the portion of the page left unmarked.the space between graphics, margins and gutters. It is the space between columns, between lines of type or figures **that provides visual breathing room for the eye**. Whitespace is an important element of design for good reason.
[image]

Google, as you can see, is a big advocate of white space in their designs. The search engine is widely regarded to have a clean design since the focus is on the main aim of the page, without massive dedication to other areas.

Answer (score 0):

Its all about user experience(UX). a good designer should know this,when your eye focus on the screen for searching topics it will always focus on center and its hard to find favorite topics when the results stick to the left without any margin.some companys like google or yahoo always consider this to get better result in the ux.